# Chat application using jms spring and activemq queue

Tags: java, spring, queue, jms, activemq-classic

So here is my problem... big problem

I have class called Startup which contains my main method which calls client class, and Client class creates a window, ChatListener for listening to the messages

Now, I need to run the Startup two times(not only two more than two actually) and perform chat operation

My question is can I achieve this functionality using queue or should switch to topic

Other thing I have partially achieved it but the problem is when I send message I cant show it in the right receiver

Code is below

Startup

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Startup {
static Long id = (long) 0;
public static String[] ARGS;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException {
    Startup s = new Startup();
    s.ARGS = args;
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringContext.xml");
    CClient client = (CClient) context.getBean("simpleClient");
}
}
```

CClient

```
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;

import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
String identifier;

public CClient(String identifier) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
}
public JTextArea taDisplay;
public void setTfInput(JTextField tfInput) {
    this.tfInput = tfInput;
}

private JTextField tfInput;
private String msg;

public void setTemplate(JmsTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public void setDestination(Destination destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}

public JmsTemplate template;
public Destination destination;

public void init() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(new JLabel("Enter Text: "));
    tfInput = new JTextField(10);
    add(tfInput);
    JButton jSend = new JButton("Send");
    add(jSend);
    taDisplay = new JTextArea(6, 30);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(taDisplay);
    add(scrollPane);
    jSend.addActionListener(this);
    setTitle("Communicator " + identifier);
    setSize(400, 200);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   try {
       if ("Send".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
           msg = tfInput.getText();

           template.send(destination, new MessageCreator() {
               public Message createMessage(Session session)
                       throws JMSException {
                   Message message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
                   message.setStringProperty("stringProperty", identifier);
                   return message;
               }
           });
       }

   } catch (Exception e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println("Error: " + e1);
   }
  }

}
```

Chat Listener:

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ChatListener implements MessageListener {

public CClient cClient;

public void onMessage(Message message) {

    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        try {
            System.out.print("hai");
            System.out.println("Received Message is " + ((TextMessage)     message).getText());
            String[] parts = Pattern.compile(":", Pattern.LITERAL).split(((TextMessage) message).getText());
            System.out.println(parts[0]);
            String frmWho = message.getStringProperty("stringProperty");
            System.out.println("From Who " + frmWho);
           cClient.taDisplay.append(((TextMessage) message).getText() + "\n");
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

    }

}

public void setcClient(CClient cClient) {
    this.cClient = cClient;
}
}
```

SpringContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">


<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL">
        <!--<value>vm://localhost</value>-->
        <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="jmsExample" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<util:constant id="constructorarg" static-field="com.communicator.Startup.ARGS"/>

<bean id="simpleClient" class="com.communicator.CClient" init-method="init">
    <constructor-arg><value>#{constructorarg}</value></constructor-arg>
    <property name="template" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageListener" class="com.communicator.ChatListener">
    <property name="cClient" ref="simpleClient"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you

Comment: a publish/subscribe topology is typically the way to model a chat network. You can probably use queues as well, but then you need to dynamically create different queues for different clients, somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of a queue is that every message is **consumed once, and only once**.

I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do:

- when you say that you need to call Startup several times, are you saying that you are effectively starting several clients on the same machine?)
- you don't describe the intended message flow: are you trying to broadcast every message to every connected client? Or are you trying to send messages from one client to the other? The answer to this question will allow you to choose between topics, respectively queues (and probably a combination of both, since most chat systems combine broadcast and unicast exchanges).
- one thing that you *could* use are JMS selectors, allowing you to filter the messages consumed by a particular client (you could use a *destination* attribute or something like that).

Comment: I have already solved the problem using the third bullet mentioned, thank you